# Conflicting jQuery Versions

Tags: jquery

The main problem is that I have 2 jQuery versions working in my website:
`1.2.6` and `2.0.3`

Most of my scripts are using `1.2.6` but only 1 script is using `2.0.3`

How can  I stop this conflict between the both jQuery versions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a pretty well covered question. I wasn't aware of what @Stijn mentioned, but yes, this is a duplicate of that question. My answer goes more generally into `noConflict` for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use jQuery.noConflict:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

That allows you to intentionally use multiple libraries which override `$` gracefully.

Here are some related questions on the topic of `.noConflict()` for you:

- [How does jQuery no conflict mode work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943109/how-does-jquery-no-conflict-mode-work)
- [How do I implement JQuery.noConflict() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict)
- [jQuery: noConflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188262/jquery-noconflict)

Usually this is used for other libraries vs. multiple jQuery versions, but the same applies to multiple jQuery versions.